# Protractor cannot click using Safari whereas same scripts working fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor

I am working on an angular app and use directconnect for Chrome and Firefox.
All my test scripts work fine but now I have a requirement to run same tests in Safari.
So I am using webdriver-manager for that.
Safari opens up my app fine and then I am able to enter login credentials with sendKeys() as well.
But When clicking on the next/login button I get the error "WebDriverError: The target element is not interactable and could not be clicked"
This is the code which is pretty straight forward.

```
  element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(username);
  console.log('Click next');
  element(by.buttonText('Next')).click();
  console.log('Entering password');
  element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
  console.log('Click sign in');
  element(by.buttonText('Sign in')).click();
```

Comment: You may need to move your mouse to that location first before you click

Comment: I tried browser.actions() mouseMove but that also gives me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202589 where safari webdriver is not able to click the the elements on webpage.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option of clicking the element using javascript executor.

```
var signIn =  element(by.buttonText('Sign in'));

await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', signIn); \\ This will click the element
```

Hope it helps you